# Exclusion validation

Tags: ext.net

I'm validating a gridpanel column against its model but having trouble with exclusion validation.
All values except 0 are valid but using the code bellow i'm getting always invalid.
Any ideas of what I' might be doing wrong?

```
<ext:ExclusionValidation Field="FormularioId" List="0" Message="Seleccione formulario" ></ext:ExclusionValidation>
```

Answer (score 0):

Copying answer to this question given by Vladimir Shcheglov in Ext.net forum:

'List="0"' issue is fixed in SVN, the fix will be available in the next public release
Workaround, define two '0'

```
List="0,0"
```